# Join Statement for Multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have a problem with displaying records once despite using inner join. 
I have posted a question which have the code here

```
SELECT transaction_information . *, customer_information . * , property_information . *, borrowers . *,  lenders . *, listing_agents . *, payoff . *,  sellers . *, selling_agents .*
FROM transaction_information
JOIN customer_information ON transaction_information.entry_no = customer_information.entry_no
JOIN property_information ON transaction_information.entry_no = property_information.entry_no
JOIN borrowers ON transaction_information.entry_no = borrowers.entry_no
JOIN lenders ON transaction_information.entry_no = lenders.entry_no
JOIN listing_agents ON transaction_information.entry_no = listing_agents.entry_no
JOIN payoff ON transaction_information.entry_no = payoff.entry_no
JOIN sellers ON transaction_information.entry_no = sellers.entry_no
JOIN selling_agents ON transaction_information.entry_no = selling_agents.entry_no
";
```

I have a form at http://208.109.186.112/kushalmn/demo1/. It has two borrower sections and I am using borrowers in one single table. Also, Each section is stored in its own table. For example, Sellers have own table, lenders have own, customer information have own and so forth. If I fill two borrower entries and say customer info section only, I get multiple rows exceeding 100 maybe.

The view page for the form can be viewed here http://208.109.186.112/kushalmn/demo1/view.php.

It seems a problem with Joins . **Common Column being `Entry no` which I am incrementing at each submit.**

Comment: Please, give us a minimal working example allowing to reproduce the issue. We don't want to waste time looking at your site and digging in 9 tables.

Comment: Okay. I gave the link for reference so that other people can get a clearer idea. Maybe you can minimalise it yourself with maybe three tables and perform a join.

Comment: Nothing wrong with JOIN, you just need to understand how it works. Start by looking up `left join` and go from there

Comment: Tried that too. But again many many records.

Comment: You need to create a very cut down example, say 2 entries in each table and then explain what you'd expect to see. Join is not going to be broken, your understanding of what it's meant to do probably is. If the structures are too big/complex to mess with then use a tool like SQL Fiddle to mock something up quickly

Comment: Is `entry_no` unique in *every* joined table?

Comment: For each submit I am making entry_no increment by one. So a common entry_no goes to all sections i.e. tables for a single submit. I have not defined any other constraints to  it.